# Parse Query "Cannot call method 'equalTo' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, types, parse-platform

I am trying to send an email parameter in the format `{"email":"test@example.com"}` to my Parse Cloud code, but when I do, I get the following error:

```
Failed with: TypeError: Cannot call method 'equalTo' of undefined
at main.js:19:8
```

Here is my code (in `main.js`, starting on line 16):

```
Parse.Cloud.define("searchFriendViaEmail", function(request, response) {
    console.log(request.params);
    var query = Parse.Query("_User");
    query.equalTo("email", request.params.email);
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            response.success(results[0]);
        },
        error: function() {
            response.error("user lookup failed");
        }
    });
});
```

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong?

Comment: It means the call to `Parse.Query("_User")` is returning `undefined`. I think you just left off `new` - should be `new Parse.Query("_User");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `new` keyword.

```
var query = new Parse.Query("_User");
```